# InDesign: creating a numbered list with custom glyphs

Tags: adobe-indesign, glyphs, signage

I'm doing a signage design in Indesign and want to use the `CIRCLED DIGIT ONE, CIRCLED DIGIT TWO, etc` number glyphs for a numbered list. I'm using Lato Medium.

Setting a custom glyph for a bulleted list is easy, but is it possible to create a style that uses other glyphs in the font set and enumerates them?

[image: example]

Note that I don't want to use another font for the numbering, rather I want to use characters in the Lato Medium font that are part of the extended unicode set of characters.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think custom glyphs is the only way. Use `Left Indent` and a negative `First Line Left Indent` to insert these glyphs by hand followed by a `TAB`.

A numbered list in ID only works with Unicodes `0031`, `0032`, `0033`, etc which normally get assigned to the plain `1`, `2`, `3` characters, including in your Lato Medium font. While the *NEGATIVE CIRCLE DIGITS* glyphs found in Lato Medium have these Unicodes for `1`, `2`, `3`: `2776`, `2777`, `2778`. To InDesign these are *meaningless* symbols, not the digits you type via your keyboard keys `1`, `2`, `3`.

On the other hand this font only has 20 *NEGATIVE CIRCLE DIGITS*, so anything above `20` could not have been displayed anyway via automatic numbering.

[image: lato glyphs]
[image]

Comment: I noticed the limit but since this just for signage I won't be going above 10. I guess its still not possible though without creating a custom font.  Thanks for the workaround with the indents.

Comment: Yeah, well automatic numbering makes sense and saves time for large volumes of text, for signage with up to 10 bullets i guess manually inserting these won't hurt much.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. Create a Paragraph Style for your numbered list. Edit that Paragraph Style and go to the Bullets and Numbering tab.

[image: Bullets and Numbering tab in Indesign]

Under Numbering Style, look for Character Style and select New Character Style...

[image: New Character Style dialog in Indesign]

In the New Character Style dialog box, select the Basic Character Formats tab and apply the Dingbat Negative font family.

[image: Basic Character Formats dialog in Indesign]

---

Given your edits, the following is one option. It is not perfect and will work best if your work is done and ready for publishing.

1. Create your list as usual, but when you edit the Paragraph Style and choose Bullets and Numbering, take out the period (so instead of <kbd>^#.^t</kbd> I would put <kbd>^#^t</kbd>).
2. Select the entire list, right click and choose Convert Numbering to Text.
3. <kbd>Cmd-F</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> and choose the Glyph tab. Set font to Lato Medium for both the Find Glyph and the Change Glyph.
4. For Find Glyph ID, choose Unicode and enter 0031. For Change Glyph ID, choose Unicode and enter 2776. Set your Search parameter to Selection (assuming you still have the entire list selected).
5. Click Find Next. If the correct numbered list glyph is selected (in this case, 1), click Change.
6. Increment each ID by 1 (Find Glyph ID becomes 0032 and Change Glyph ID becomes 2777).

Repeat steps 6 and 7 until you get to the end of your list.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. I want to glyphs in the Lato font - not another font - thats easy enough to do.

Comment: I certainly did, since you said, "I ... want to use the DINGBAT NEGATIVE number glyphs for a numbered list."

Comment: Ah, sorry they are actually called - `CIRCLED DIDGET ONE, ...` don't know why I got another name when hovering over the glyph.

Comment: Okay, I just saw your edit. I will amend my answer for one possible solution. Lucian's answer is good and provides another way.